# CORS will not enable with MAMP localhost

Tags: .htaccess, cors, mamp-pro

I've built a RESTful Api in PHP on a local machine and everything is working perfectly. Preflight requests are sending the correct responses etc, everything handled by PHP is working like a dream.

But if I try to access an image in a public folder (programatically via javascript in this instance) I'm getting the infuriating :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/tmp/avatars/user.jpg' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've set the following in the `.htaccess` file in the public root dir, and in the MAMP Apache `<Directory>` and `<VirtualHost>` directives but it is just refusing to work.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
```

CORS is a pain in the arse at the best of times, but this is just ridiculous. Why isn't this working?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change the `httpd.conf` file from apache folder in MAMP and add the following code on the `Directory` tag (line204-208).

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"  
</Directory>
```

You can open with nano and modify it.

```
#nano /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf
```

Then restart your MAMP server and should be working properly.

I solved the same issue like that.

Also you can solve it using a Google Chrome Extension called "Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

But be aware that this will only work with your Chrome Browser. The most efficient solution is the first one, modifying the configuration file on the server.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks this does work. At the time I ended up installing the Chrome Extension and that fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

FYI, the previous solution didn't solve the problem for me. I have MAMP PRO 6.0.1.

I solved it by adding

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

To the Additional parameters for  directive:

[MAMP Pro Apache configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D3pS.png)

Comment: For older versions of MAMP Pro add Headers into `<VirtualHost></VirtualHost>` tags on line#690-728 as follow:

```
<VirtualHost>
 ...
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart servers and you are done.

Comment: This also worked for me on MAMP Pro 6, whereas the accepted answer didn't.